# Javascript AJAX SyntaxError: Unexpected token E in JSON at position 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am using AJAX to make HTTP requests to my node.js server. However, my AJAX requests keep returning the error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token E in JSON at position 0` (there's no error returned on the server side).

While browsing other SO questions, I found the solution is to use `JSON.stringify()` on my data object.. but I still get the same error:

```
var postData = { 
  company_id: 'cid',
  credentials: 
   { first_name: 'van',
     last_name: 'jones',
     phone_number: '1035191043',
     email: 'van.jones@gmail.com'},
  company: 
   { company_name: 'cnn',
     company_email: 'info@cnn.com',
     company_phone_number: '2800231374',
     company_notes: '' },
  shipping_address: 
   { addr_1: 'addr1',
     addr_2: 'addr2',
     city: 'city',
     state: 'state',
     zip: 'zip' },
  billing_address: 
   { addr_1: 'addr1',
     addr_2: 'addr2',
     city: 'city',
     state: 'state',
     zip: 'zip' },
  some_bool: true,
  another_bool: true,
  hostname: 'localhost' 
}

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'some_url',
  data: JSON.stringify(postData),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function(data, status) {
    console.log('success')
  },
  error: function(a, b, c) {
    console.log(a);
    console.log(b);
    console.log(c);
    // returns SyntaxError: Unexpected token E in JSON at position 0
  }
});
```

Does anyone know what I might be missing?

Thank you.

Comment: Inspect actual response body in browser dev tools network, it's clearly not valid json being sent back from server

Comment: The json you posted in your question is invalid, it misses `}`, after credentials property more exactly.

Comment: Missing a closing } after email in the credentials section.

Comment: thanks all - that was a bad copy & paste.. i added in the missing `}`; still having the same issue though...

Comment: That means that your server is returning invalid json. Press `F12` and go to the Network tab and watch what the server is sending.

Comment: The Best Friend is Browser Net Panel XHR tab. Whenever Ajax use check what you getting in response. If it's JSON, copy the JSON response from Browser's Net Panle and try JSON lint to find what exactly problem in response....

Answer (score 0):

From my experience such information always ment some trouble server-side (I know you say there isn't, but still..), e.g. SQL query error. Try incorporating similar code to your error handling function. It may help you solve your problem.

```
error: function(xhr) {
  try {
    var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    console.log('Success');
    console.log(response);
  }
  catch (e) {
    var response = xhr.responseText;
    console.log(
      'There was an error: \n -> '
      + e + '\n'
      + 'Complete server response: \n -->'
      + response
    );
  }
}
```